# Eclipse Templates, Generate a handle-name

Tags: java, eclipse

first of all, excuse my english. Its a bit rusty.

In my work we have to change from JDeveloper to Eclipse. I now start to define some Code-Templates. The most of them are no Problem to transfer.

I miss something in the variables in Eclipse.

I try to write our "inj" Template.

```
${:import(javax.inject.Inject)}
@Inject
${type} ${THE_PROBLEM}; 
${cursor}
```

Till now, we only have to type inj and write the name of the type. The handle get the name from the type. Same word, only with a small letter in the beginning. Is there a way to make this in Eclipse?